# Получить значения из select

Tags: php, javascript

view

```
<select  name="text_sms" id="text_sms" style="height: 38px;" >
 <option value="*">-Выберите шаблон-</option>
 <?php foreach($sms_text as $text){ ?>
 <option data-ttn="<?php echo $sms['ttn']?>" value="<?php echo $text['id']?>"><?php echo $text['name']?></option> <?php } ?>
 </select>

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text_sms').change(function () {
        var id_text = $('#text_sms').val();

        var ttn_number = $(this).data('ttn');// не находит 

        console.log(ttn_number);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php?route=account/order/text_template',
            data:{ "id_text":id_text },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#text_template').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Можно передать значения из `option data-ttn="<?php echo $sms['ttn']?>"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно получить "data-ttn" выбранной option:

```
$("#text_sms option:selected").attr('data-ttn');
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь то что нужно .

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("select").on("change", () => {
  alert($("select option:selected").data('test'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test">
  <option value="1" data-test="a1">1</option>
  <option value="2" data-test="a2">2</option>
  <option value="3" data-test="a3">3</option>
  <option value="4" data-test="a4">4</option>
</select>
```